# How would using caching nginx template affect adsense?

Tags: nginx, cache

I'm considering using the nginx template below for WP sites with adsense on them.
Would that cache the adsense ads too and make the clicks invalid?

```
server {
listen      %ip%:%proxy_port%;
server_name %domain_idn% %alias_idn%;
error_log  /var/log/%web_system%/domains/%domain%.error.log error;

location / {
    proxy_pass      http://%ip%:%web_port%;

    proxy_cache cache;
    proxy_cache_valid 15m;
    proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
    proxy_no_cache $no_cache;
    proxy_cache_bypass $no_cache;
    proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_session $http_x_update;

    location ~* ^.+\.(%proxy_extentions%)$ {
        proxy_cache    off;
        root           %docroot%;
        access_log     /var/log/%web_system%/domains/%domain%.log combined;
        access_log     /var/log/%web_system%/domains/%domain%.bytes bytes;
        expires        max;
        try_files      $uri @fallback;
    }
}

location /error/ {
    alias   %home%/%user%/web/%domain%/document_errors/;
}

location @fallback {
    proxy_pass      http://%ip%:%web_port%;
}

location ~ /\.ht    {return 404;}
location ~ /\.svn/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.git/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.hg/   {return 404;}
location ~ /\.bzr/  {return 404;}

include %home%/%user%/conf/web/nginx.%domain%.conf*;
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Adsense resources are hosted on google's side, not yours.

Comment: They are, but it seems there are many factors that would affect adsense, how fast page loads, what IP your website has, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are some no-so-obvious ways that a cache server would negatively affect your AdSense earnings, I am going trough that now, I will add here when I have new info.

- Site started to **load faster than the ads**, user can scroll to bottom of page and the ad is loaded on top (out of view), check your "active view viewable" changes and other metrics that might indicate this. Google also uses this as a quality signal: how fast a user clicks on an ad, they claim that clicking too fast = you don't know what you clicked = invalid click.
- If the cache servers have new public IPs (your site starts using **new IP**), then your reputation might be affected by "**bad neighborhood**" where your ranks are decreased because of other malicious sites from same IP class, or because of previous IP owner(s).
- New cache proxy usually means different https cert or settings, apache and nginx use different ssl settings, some settings might prevent older clients from viewing the site, bad ssl settings can affect your rankings or reputation. Test cert with something like SslLabs SSL test.

Answer (score -2):

Adsense earnings drop when you use caching programs.  I've had it go from earning $300 a day to $3.00 a day and when I turned off caching it went right back up to $300.  This guy above is mistaken for saying it cached on google's side not yours.  Your caching plugins will cache the google code, and it will not count your views just your clicks.

Comment: If that happened to you, then you did something seriously wrong in your caching configuration.

Comment: [adsense is just a script tag](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/181960?hl=en) - the code doesn't change from one request to another, it makes no difference whatsoever whether it's in cached/a static html page or served dynamically. If you can provide something more substantial than FUD as to your particular scenario, it'd be possible to say what happened. Even with that though -1 for an anecdotal, easily refutable answer.

Comment: Well I've provided the exact template code for a reason. So someone more knowledgable than me can say for sure if that would cache google adsense ads as well.
From my understanding it will render the page once per 15 mins, and for the rest of those 15 mins will serve the same page as if it was static html.
Is that right?

Comment: From my recent experience, something is happening with nginx cache + adsense but not sure what yet, it might trigger some invalid activity filters when site speed increases (and user engagement), OR some caching triggers like the beacons in PageSpeed reach some adsense urls and are identified as invalid activity.